Samba Share With Nginx
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I recently installed Nginx. Odd thing is now I can't connect to my Ubuntu samba share. I look at sudo ufw app list and see it in there. Is there something else I need to white list it in? Before I was able to connect fine.
Thanks

Is the Samba service running?
